# Find and add string in C#

Tags: c#

I am keeping values in two variables.

```
variable1 = a1, b1, c1
variable2 = b1, x1, y1
```

I want to search the variable2 and when I found b1 then I need my variable1 looks like - `a1, b1, x1, y1, c1`

Could someone help me to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: This question is not very clear, try to clarify what you are trying to do please.

Comment: Could you show what you tried please and why it is not working?

Comment: @TylerNichols, I like to search variable2 for example value b1, if I found the value than I will add rest of the variable2 values in variable1 after b1.

Comment: @FirstStep, I did not find any way to do this

Comment: Are you talking about arrays of strings, strings concatenated together, what?

Comment: @TylerNichols, string concatenated only not arrays, but I need to add after the variable1 value b1 not end of the variable1 strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let variable1 and variable2 be two list, then you can do the following operation to get the expected output:

```
 List<string> variable1 = new List<string>() { "a1", "b1", "c1" };
 List<string> variable2 = new List<string>() { "b1", "x1", "y1" };
 foreach (string item in variable2)
 {
     var index = variable1.FindIndex(x => x == item);
     if (index != -1)
     {
         variable1[index] = String.Join(",", variable2);
     }
 }
 Console.WriteLine("Outpur is {0}", String.Join(",", variable1));
```

Output will be : `a1, b1, x1, y1, c1`, the match in the first array will be replaced with the entire second array.

Comment: Many thanks, though it is possible do the same thing with string instead of list of strings.

Comment: You can convert the string into list of strings using `.Split()` then apply the same principle